# Can an ASP.NET app and Console app work off of the same class library DLLs?

Tags: asp.net, .net, dll

My ASP.NET 4.5 application references a class library project.  All the DLLs are in the normal place - the BIN folder of the website.  I'd like to create a Console app that references the same class library project.  I can obviously deploy that Console app in a separate folder outside the website.  BUT I was curious **if it would also be possible to put the Console App EXE in the website BIN folder and have both the ASP.NET website and the Console App running off of the same DLLs in the same physical folder?**

I'm aware that the Console App and Website would be running in different app domains so there wouldn't be any shared static variables, etc, which is okay.  I wasn't sure if two separate apps / app domains could safely reference the same physical DLLs.  For example, perhaps errors could arise due to locking where the website process has locked a DLL preventing the console app from using it or vice versa.  Or any other situation like this where it may be ill-advised to have these 2 apps accessing the same DLL's at the same time.

Comment: You should keep them two separate projects and reference dlls that you need in dependent project. **Keeping them in one would be bad practice and I bet you're going to cause some weird tfs issues.

Answer (score 2):

> it would also be possible to put the Console App EXE in the website BIN folder and have both the ASP.NET website and the Console App running off of the same DLLs in the same physical folder?

You can probably do it, but I wouldn't.  There is not normally any issue at all in sharing assembly binaries (after all, all the assemblies in the [GAC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz(v=vs.110).aspx) are shared).  The only thing I might be hesitant about is that you will have an app domain user with execute access to that Bin folder, and therefore that console app.  Probably not the greatest.  There may be other problems too, I'm not sure-- I've honestly never seen anybody set up anything like this on purpose.  The typical procedure is to create a separate folder for each application, and put any shared DLLs into the GAC.

> or example, perhaps errors could arise due to locking where the website process has locked a DLL preventing the console app from using it or vice versa.

You're pretty safe here.  Your web site doesn't actually run off of the DLLs in the bin folder.  While it does monitor the bin folder for any changes, all the files in bin are [copied to a temporary folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx) and executed there (the exact folder is `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\Temporary ASP.NET Files`).  This temporary cache mechanism is what allows you to deploy an ASP.NET site using [xcopy deployment](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/326355) without bringing the site down.

On the other hand, running your console app would interfere with the *deployment* of your web site (you couldn't perform any web deployments while the console app is running, unless they were markup only), so there is that.

Comment: Helpful feedback, thanks John.  I suppose you are correct that it's probably better to avoid.  I was mainly trying to avoid an extra deployment (redeploying the same class library DLL's to 2 locations).  Automating deployment should solve that.  Your last point is quite valid about not being able to update the web site if the console app is running.